# Jquery delay event until the user has finished typing

Tags: jquery, action, wait

A function to be launched let's say a second and a half after the user has finished typing the last type. I have this piece of code but everytime that the user is making one type the script is launched which I don't want:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  var $firstname    = $("#firstname");

  $firstname.keyup(function()
  {
    var content = $("#firstname").val();
    $.post("ajax.php", { firstname: content}, function(result){
        var contentDiv = $("#ContainerValidation");
        contentDiv.fadeOut(400, function(){ contentDiv.html(result); });
        contentDiv.fadeIn(400);
        contentDiv.fadeOut(5000);
      });
    });
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The code you posted does not run when the user provides any input. It is only run once when the page loads.

Comment: How will you come to know that user has finished his typing?

Comment: how do you confirm user has finished typing? which key does user hit to finish typing?

Comment: @Felix: I corrected the code. Sorry.

Comment: @Vikram and run... I am sure there is a trick to judge if a user has finished typing a key like running the script waiting 2 segonds and then if the user types again the script time is reseted or something like that. Like this the entire script is launched only once or be limited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it would be sufficient to start a timer that waits 1.5 seconds and is aborted if the user continues typing during that time:

```
function send() {
    $.post("ajax.php", { firstname: $firstname.val()}, function(result){
        $("#ContainerValidation")
           .fadeOut(400, function(){ $(this).html(result); })
           .fadeIn(400)
           .fadeOut(5000);
    });
}

var timer = null;
$firstname.keyup(function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(send, 1500);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You understood the problem but the script is delayed by 1.5 seconds(it is ok) but if I type two caracters the script still running twice.

Comment: Oh, I made a slight mistake. You have to remove `var` inside the function. Updated. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gjFm9/

Comment: Instead of using a global variable, you could store the timer using `$(this).data()`

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Right. `timer` is actually not global, as the whole code is supposed to be in the `ready` handler. But you have a valid point.

Answer (score 3):

What you'll want is a debouncing script.

A very easy solution would be embedding the [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) library, it contains such a function: http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#debounce

You'd use it like this:

```
$firstname.keyup(_.debounce(function () {
    var content = $("#firstname").val();
    $.post("ajax.php", {
        firstname: content
    }, function (result) {
        var contentDiv = $("#ContainerValidation");
        contentDiv.fadeOut(400, function () {
            contentDiv.html(result);
        });
        contentDiv.fadeIn(400);
        contentDiv.fadeOut(5000);
    });
}, 1500));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Master.. I'll keep in mind that solution. Felix gave me an equivalent solution without this library. Still I will take a look to this one. I Give you a point up anyways.